# Substring can be rearranged to match another string

Tags: python, string

I am attempting a CodeWars question where it is required to create a function that returns `True` if a portion of `str1` characters can be rearranged to match `str2` and `False` otherwise. My code is as follows:

```
def scramble(str1, str2):
    l = list(str2)
    le = len(str2)
    count = 0
    for i in l:
        if i in str1:
            count+=1 
        else:
            count = count
    return True if count == le else False
```

I appear to be failing the performance tests which test for two strings up to 600000 characters so I was wondering if theres a better way to do this.

Comment: Irrelevant, but I'll point this out: `return True if count == le else False` is redundant. Just write `return count == le`.

Comment: `count = count` does nothing.  Omit the `else` clause.

Comment: What do you mean by "a portion of" `str1` characters? Do you mean that `str2` can be formed from *some* of `str1`'s characters, or do they have to be from all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `collections.Counter` and `all()` to check if we have enough characters in `str1`:

```
from collections import Counter

def scramble(str1, str2):
    c1 = Counter(str1)
    c2 = Counter(str2)
    return all(k in c1 and c1[k] >= c2[k] for k in c2)

v = scramble('ab', 'aa')
print(v)
```

Prints:

```
False
```

More checks:

```
scramble('abcd', 'cbda')  # True
scramble('bcd', 'cbda')   # False
scramble('abcd', 'acbda') # False
```

Answer (score 6):

First, your code doesn't work; it doesn't handle duplicates correctly.  Second, it *is* slow, as you've used an **O(n*m))** algorithm: you check each character of one string for inclusion in a list of the others.

A few hints:

Don't make a new list from a string; simply iterate over the string.

```
for char in str2:
```

will do the job.

Make a way of checking the chars in str1 only once.  A good way would be to count the quantity of each character, so you have an "inventory".  You can do this with a dictionary.  Even better, use a collections.Counter object.

If you inventory the chars in both strings, you can simply compare them; if each char of `str2` is no more frequent than that char in `str1`, you return success.